Export charts from Power BI into Word
I am working in Power BI with the offline desktop version. Within Power BI, I can prepare good charts, but a problem arises when I want to extract these charts into a Word document.
One option is to export all charts as PDFs and then use a snipping tool to paste them into Word. However, this option is not ideal because it affects the quality of the exported charts.
Can anybody help me with how to export these charts with high quality into Word?
